# remove items with low frequency

Tags: python, numpy

Let's consider the array of length `n`:

```
y=np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,4,1,1,1])
```

and the matrix `X` of size `n` x `m`.

I want to remove items of `y` and rows of `X`, for which the corresponding value of `y` has low frequency.

I figured out this would give me the values of `y` which should be removed:

```
>>> items, count = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
>>> to_remove = items[count < 3]                           # array([4])
```

and this would remove the items:

```
>>> X=X[y != to_remove,:]
>>> y=y[y != to_remove]
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

While the code above works when there is only one label to remove, it fails when there are multiple values of `y` with low frequency (i.e. `y=np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,4,1,1,1,5,5,1,1])` would cause `to_remove` to be `array([4, 5])`):

```
>>> y[y != to_remove,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

How to fix this in a concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an additional output parameter `return_inverse` in [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) like so -

```
def unique_where(y):
    _, idx, count = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)
    return y[np.in1d(idx,np.where(count>=3)[0])]

def unique_arange(y):
    _, idx, count = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)
    return y[np.in1d(idx,np.arange(count.size)[count>=3])]
```

You can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) for counting that is supposedly pretty efficient at counting and might suit it better here, assuming `y` contains non-negative numbers, like so -

```
def bincount_where(y):
    counts = np.bincount(y)
    return y[np.in1d(y,np.where(counts>=3)[0])]

def bincount_arange(y):
    counts = np.bincount(y)
    return y[np.in1d(y,np.arange(y.max())[counts>=3])]
```

Runtime tests -

This section times the above listed three approaches alongwith the approach listed in [`@Ashwini Chaudhary's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31762692/3293881) -

```
In [85]: y = np.random.randint(0,100000,50000)

In [90]: def unique_items_indexed(y): # @Ashwini Chaudhary's solution
        ...:     items, count = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
        ...:     return y[np.in1d(y, items[count >= 3])]
        ...: 

In [115]: %timeit unique_items_indexed(y)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.8 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit unique_where(y)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.9 ms per loop

In [117]: %timeit unique_arange(y)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.5 ms per loop

In [118]: %timeit bincount_where(y)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop

In [119]: %timeit bincount_arange(y)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: did you choose to use `np.in1d(idx, np.where(count>=3)[0])` instead of `np.in1d(y, items[count>=3])` for a particular reason? e.g. performance?

Comment: @mescalinum Functionally those two are same things, but one is indexing into `items`, which is of a smaller datasize than `y` and one is into `idx`, which is already of the same size as `y`. It would be interesting to test out for performance and memory.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> y = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,4,1,1,1,5,5,1,1])
>>> items, count = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
>>> to_remove = items[count < 3]
>>> y[~np.in1d(y, to_remove)]
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one value in `to_remove` the operation is ill defined:

```
>>> to_remove
array([4, 5])
>>> y != to_remove
True
```

Use the operator `in1d`:

```
>>> ~np.in1d(y, to_remove)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```